# How to adjust direction of volume displacement sample radius in blender's mesh to volume workflow?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, displacement

I'm wondering, does anyone know how to gain more control over the volume displace modifier? Specifically, I'd like to change the direction of where the displacement adds volume through the increased sample radius. It seems by default to point in the negative x and z direction. I'm sure there's a reason in Blender it goes for that, but I'd like to know why. And if there's anything I can change to disperse the displacement in all directions from the object for example.

Thanks!

[image: Screenshot of converted volume to mesh displacing in one direction with volume object modifiers on the right]
[image]

Comment: The _Mid Level_ in your _Volume Displace_ modifier is set to X = 1.2, Y = 1 and Z = 1. Values above 0.5 shift in negative direction, values below 0.5 shift in positive direction. So judging from the settings it should not only shift in negative X and Z direction, but negative Y as well. The _Strength_ factor exaggerates this shift. The other problem is, the _Clouds_ texture produces random values between 0 and 1 with an average of 0.5, which usually shift the values in positive X, Y and Z direction... and not to forget the Empty. All these direction shifts are battling each other ;)

Comment: Oh, got it! I see how that makes sense. Unfortunately, I have the same issue where the excess displacement only affects the front and left of the face despite both mid levels and empty location being in the positive now. The mid levels seem to shift the character model around its volume boundary but don't change how the distortion sample radius is extruded... Mainly I'd like to emphasize the extruded distortion evenly around the model, but no settings have helped with that so far. Thanks for the comment, I'm making better sense of what's going on here. b^.^d